# How to get class list of the <HTML> element?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I would like to access the class list of the html element (that is in this case I'd like to know if my-class is set on html):

```
<html class="my-class">
...
</html>
```

How can I do that with JavaScript?

Comment: `document.documentElement` get's the HTML element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList then can access the classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the element and then classList:

`document.querySelector('html').classList` or if you have multiple clsases in your element then you can select by class to get the other classes from this element too.
`document.querySelector('.my-class').classList`

Comment: This is also valid, +1. ^^ First I was laughing when you've done '.my-class' :)) that was valid but defeated the purpose of the question.

Comment: @BarneySzabolcs lol i just sat in front of the monitor and wondered if that was a clever answer from me ... but it could be that there are several classes and then you would also reach the others via my-class.

Comment: Yes, that's also true. And in fact, your answer with 'html' is more expressive than documentElement.